# iOS - UIButton image insets issue

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, interface-builder, uiedgeinsets

I set up an image for a UIButton in interface builder and I'm having an issue.  I set the edge insets of the image (top: ~15, bottom: ~15) to make it fit better within the button.  Unfortunately, since the button itself has an aspect ratio constraint to make it size well between different devices, on the smaller devices the static edge insets make the button's image look tiny.  Any way to just set a manual height and width for this button's image?

### iphone 5s

[image]

### iphone 6

[image]

Comment: Can you please separate your two problems into two different questions?

Comment: attache some screen shot whats your requirement is its hard to understand ...